# Dont download images yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Dont work upload images on yii2... write dont have $addImgFile->extension;...
if i write him .png , i see other error
Exception 'Error' with message 'Call to a member function saveAs() on null'

```
public function actionMultipleImg()
{
    $this->enableCsrfValidation = false;
    if (\Yii::$app->request->isPost) {
        $post = \Yii::$app->request->post();
       
        $dir = \Yii::getAlias('@productImgPath') . '/additional-image/';
        $result_link = str_replace('administrator', '', Url::home(true)) . 'storage/additional-image/';
        $addImgFile = UploadedFile::getInstanceByName('ProductImage[attachment]');

        $modelProductImage = new ProductImage();
        $modelProductImage->filename = strtotime('now') . '_' . \Yii::$app->getSecurity()->generateRandomString(6) . '.'.$addImgFile->extension;
        $modelProductImage->load($post);
        $modelProductImage->validate();
    
        if ($modelProductImage->hasErrors()) {
            $result = ['error' => $modelProductImage->getFirstError('addImgFile')];
        } else {
            if ($addImgFile->saveAs($dir . $modelProductImage->filename)) {
                $imag = \Yii::$app->image->load($dir . $modelProductImage->filename);
                $imag->save($dir . $modelProductImage->filename, 90);
                $result = ['filelink' => $result_link . $modelProductImage->filename, 'filename' => $modelProductImage->filename];
            } else {
                $result = ['error' => 'Ошибка'];
            }//else
        }//else
        $modelProductImage->save();
        \Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;

        return $result;
    } else {
        throw new BadRequestHttpException('Only POST is allowed');
    }
}//action multiple img
```

my view form where download image

```
<?php echo FileInput::widget([
            'name' => 'ProductImage[attachment]',
            'options' => ['accept' => 'image/*','multiple' => true],
            'pluginOptions' => [
                'deleteUrl' => Url::toRoute(['/product/delete-image']),
                'initialPreview' => $model->imagesLinks,
                'initialPreviewAsData'=>true,
                'overwriteInitial' => false,
                'initialPreviewConfig' => $model->imagesLinksData,
                'uploadUrl' => Url::to(['/product/multiple-img']),
                'uploadExtraData' => [
                    'ProductImage[product_id]' => $model->id,
                ],
                'maxFileCount' => 10
            ],
            'pluginEvents' => [
                'filesorted' => new JsExpression('function(event, params){
                    $.post("' . Url::toRoute(["/product/sort-image", "id"=>$model->id]) . '", {position:params});
                 }')
            ],
        ]);?>
```

Comment: Obviusly `$addImgFile` is null. Can you dump your form post? Your inout file is multiple, but you try to get one instance ande save it?

Comment: @vvpanchev
array(5) {
  ["fileId"]=>
  string(30) "1147972_0_fGOH_EZ-GIQ3EePJ.png"
  ["initialPreview"]=>
  string(2) "[]"
  ["initialPreviewConfig"]=>
  string(2) "[]"
  ["initialPreviewThumbTags"]=>
  string(2) "[]"
  ["ProductImage"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["product_id"]=>
    string(4) "1366"
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

and its helped

```
$addImgFile = UploadedFile::getInstanceByName('ProductImage[attachment][0]');
```